# No Plymouth splash on startup?

Tags: ati, plymouth

I recently bought a new laptop with an ATI Mobility Radeon 5470HD graphics card in it and installed Ubuntu. Everything works just fine, but at the startup, no Plymouth splash screen comes up, just a black screen with a white dash. The splash screen on shutdown works fine though.

Does anybody know how to fix this so I can get some eyecandy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plymouth doesn't work with binary released drivers....there's a solution but it involves a bit of legwork.  For a scripted solution try this: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html